# Integrating Stylecop in Jenkins for .NET project

Tags: c#, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, stylecop

I have installed Jenkins on windows machine and it's building the .NET code properly.  I have installed the Violations plugin in Jenkins to validate Style cop warnings . While building the solution the StyleCop validations are shown in the Jenkins console output page as below

```
  C:\Users\\\\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(32,1): warning : SP2000 : StyleCopPlus.StyleCopPlus :  Invalid spacing at the end of the line. [C:\Users\\\\\Midhun.csproj]

    1660 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:04.35 Finished: SUCCESS
```

But it's not showing any thing in the violations page.

I add the below in the .csproj

```
 <StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
```

After that jenkins build was failing. But still violations page was coming emtpy.

I went through so many articles , but not able to clearly understand what need to be done. I could n't find any step by step tutorial for this . If anybody can post a step by step tutorial or a link that would be great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this fixed . Below are detailed steps how to solve this issue.

1. Add Violations plugin in Jenkins
2. In post build steps add Report Violations .Specify where the stylecopviolations.xml file is generated.

> This is file will be created **jenkins workspace folder** -> Application Folder -> Obj - > Debug - > Stylecopviolations.xml . So in the below section we need to specify as * / */ */ SyleCopViolations.xml .

3. Now you will be able to see the stylecop violations in violations page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help: **/*/StyleCopViolations.xml

Comment: describe your answer some more